# Facebook OAuth Redirect field missing on new interface

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

As of July 2016, Facebook changed their developers dashboard and the OAuth field is no longer under the `Settings>Advanced` where it used to be.

You will also see message, "Client oauth login is enabled but you havn't listed and valid OAuth redirect URIs" and a link that takes you to documentation that doesnt explain where the field/option has moved too.

I looked everywhere for the setting though couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found it under `Add Product` in the left hand sidebar..

From there you can enable OAuth and the field will be available again under `Settings>Advanced` where is used to always show.

Hope this helps. Took me a day to figure it out.